# Oracle 11g dmp import. ORA-39000 / ORA-39143 Errors

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g

iam really new in oracle and databases at all.
So sorry for a maybe stupid question.

Here is my problem. I have a DB export (not mine so i dont know how it was exported: are there differences?) and i want to import it with the following script:

```
@Echo off
Break off
Rem fullimpdp.cmd
set NLS_LANG=american_america.WE8MSWIN1252
set ORACLE_HOME=C:\Oracle\ora11
Set DUMP_HOME=C:\DBDump
set /p ORACLE_SID="Oracle_sid = "
set /p FILE="Dump file name = "
if exist %DUMP_HOME%SetBackupDir_%ORACLE_SID%.sql del /F /Q %DUMP_HOME%SetBackupDir_%ORACLE_SID%.sql
echo CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY backup_dir AS '%DUMP_HOME%'; >%DUMP_HOME%SetBackupDir_%ORACLE_SID%.sql
echo CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY dmpdir AS '%DUMP_HOME%'; >>%DUMP_HOME%SetBackupDir_%ORACLE_SID%.sql
echo commit; >>%DUMP_HOME%SetBackupDir_%ORACLE_SID%.sql
echo exit    >>%DUMP_HOME%SetBackupDir_%ORACLE_SID%.sql
set ORACLE_SID=%ORACLE_SID%
%ORACLE_HOME%\bin\sqlplus xpower/xpower @%DUMP_HOME%SetBackupDir_%ORACLE_SID%.sql
%ORACLE_HOME%\bin\impdp xpower/xpower FULL=y DIRECTORY=backup_dir DUMPFILE=%FILE% logfile=impdp_%ORACLE_SID%.log JOB_NAME=impfull_%Oracle_sid%
if exist %DUMP_HOME%SetBackupDir_%ORACLE_SID%.sql del /F /Q %DUMP_HOME%SetBackupDir_%ORACLE_SID%.sql
pause
```

But not the following errors occur:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-39143: dump file "C:\DBDump\ev122.dmp" may be an original export dump file
```

What is wrong? How can i fix it in this script?
And how can i import the file not using the script? I read about the imp file=filename command. but where to type it in? :)

Thank you.

BR

Comment: This message "*may be an original export dump file*" tells you what the problem is. You need to use the (deprecated) `imp` tool, not the new `impdp` tool. Note that `imp` works on files located on the client (where `imp` is running)

Comment: and how do i use the `imp` tool?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try like this,

```
imp xpower/xpower FULL=y file=<file_name>.dmp log=log_file_name.log
```

Or you can import using system user,

```
imp system/<password> file=<file_name>.dmp log=log_file_name.log fromuser = <from_user_name> touser= xpower
```

Comment: Thank you. and how do i choose the database i want to import in?

Comment: You can mention the dbname in imp command. like,
`imp <username>/<password>@dbname ....`

Comment: Thank you. But where should i typ that command in? sorry - but iam really new :)

Comment: You need to run this command in the path where your dumpfile exists.

Comment: or you can use `file=/path/to/dump.dmp` and run it anywhere.. Thank you btw, you saved a critical data today :)

Comment: Just to mention that this way can be used to import files exported by user in TOAD. To Oracle new comers this can be a life saver.

Answer (score 3):

impdp command is used to import dump files exported by data pump. Try to use "imp" command.

Answer (score 3):

importing dump file in oracle 11g

In SQL Command Line,

1. CREATE USER username IDENTIFIED BY password
2. grant dba to username;

In Command Line,

1. imp userid=username/password FULL=y FILE="D:\yourdumpfilename.dmp"

Note ..Be sure the path of your dump file .

Answer (score 2):

@user2794543

Go to your ***Command-Prompt*** (Ctrl+R on your desktop -> type ***cmd*** in search box -> hit enter -> you will land in Command Prompt).

Now, change your directory to root C: (type *"cd.."* -> hit enter -> type *"cd.."* gain -> hit enter -> now you are at root C: directory).

Next you have to import using *"imp"* and not *"impdp"*. Type the following command line :

```
imp userid=system/[password]  file=[drive]:\[folder]\[dump_file_name].dmp full=y;
```

Hit enter and wait for the process flow.

*Ignore the square braces. They are for referencial purpose.

Answer (score 0):

DMP was exported by imp.exe utility of Oracle 12c and I was getting an error while trying import by imp.exe of Oracle 11g. Resolution in my case is: copy and paste imp.exe from 12c to 11g ...\bin folder and succesfully imported.

Answer (score 0):

Below example worked for me:

```
imp userid=solfis/solfis  file=fissetup_110.dmp full=y;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having trouble
use `imp` to import .dmp file in 19c database. write `imp` in powershell and sql will drive you through all the process.